# Why doesn't option CoordinatesToolsOptions have any effect?

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

I copied the code below from

[`http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinatesToolOptions.html`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinatesToolOptions.html)

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> 
    Function[pt, Row[{"sin(", pt[[1]], ") = ", Sin[pt[[1]]]}]]}]
```

If I execute this command, right-click on the plot, choose Get Coordinates, and then hover over the plot, I get information like this: $\{3.17069,-0.327141\}$ on the screen. The option `CoordinatesToolsOptions` does not seem to have any effect.

Why doesn't this code work properly?

I am running `Mathematica 11`.

Comment: Works in 10.4.1, but not in 11.

Comment: Looks like the reference page you linked to is down too.

Comment: @N.J.Evans - It wasn't down earlier today.

Comment: Maybe your post led to a cover-up! :P

Comment: @N.J.Evans The link was incorrect. Repaired it.

Comment: I can confirm @J.M.'s results. Looks like a bug. Could you report it to support@wolfram.com?

Comment: It's already known.